# Is it possible to base data validation on a string in a single cell in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, validation, reference, formula

I am building a multilevel dependent dropdown structure in Excel based on a parent-child structure. Building this with vba is not a problem but the problem is reopening the file. It removes the validation because they have too many characters (more than 255?)

The generated validation strings are too long for Excel to store so they are removed after reopening.

A solution could be to write the validation string in a cell and base the validation on this cell value. Only problem is when i link the data validation to this cell its only one option.

the value in the cell is something like A,B,C,D (already tried with or without "")

Does anyone have a suggestion for an excel formula to use in the data validation to generate multiple options from a string like A,B,C,D located in one single cell.

Comment: UDF. That way you can use `=VALIDATE(A1)` if A1 is the cell you wish to validate. Then you create your validation script in VBA

Comment: If you are already using VBA and have very complex validation rules, why not validate in `Worksheet_Change` event?

Answer (score 1):

TNX for the support.

The solution was a bit more difficult.

I was able to make it work but only by combining VBA and Excel Formulas. Also i added a value to the dataSource with both the id and optionid in it.

**Excel:**

For The data validation i use an fuction who utilizes an offset which is dynamic and based on 2 values. This way i dont get the error that a validation is more than 255 characters.

data validation formula:
=OFFSET(List!$A$2;MATCH(CONCATENATE(V18;"|";E18);List!$F:$F;0)-2;1;COUNTIF(List!$F:$F;CONCATENATE(V18;"|";E18)))

One is for the id and one is the optionid.

**VBA:**

I now use the on change event to produce the values needed for the dropdowns(data validation) but not letting vba insert the values for the data validation. It gets these values via a pre-loaded array which is started with a workbook_open event. (if this isnt loaded it will load it again).

When i select an item it writes the id and optionid to a different cell. I then use these to produce the next dropdowns etc with the offset function. (one dropdown can result in multiple rows of new dropdowns)

- Also added some functionality for delete and change (in the middle) events.
- Also the onChange event now triggers the next dropdown and write its value if there is only one option. This will of course trigger the next.